# Cartesian closed subcategories of compact Hausdorff topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

The category of compact Hausdorff topological spaces is famously not cartesian closed. I was wondering how much more one has to assume to actually arrive to a cartesian closed category.

For example, if we further assume total disconnectedness, i.e we end up with the category of Stone spaces, do we get cartesian closedness or still not?

Comment: I don't understand...what is wrong with my question?

Comment: You can find a detailed discussion at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convenient+category+of+topological+spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stone spaces are not cartesian closed, and I don't know of any interesting subcategory of compact Hausdorff spaces that is.  Typically, you get an interesting cartesian closed category related to compact Hausdorff spaces by allowing *more* spaces, not less: the problem is not that your spaces are too general, but simply that the natural topology on the set of all continuous maps between two spaces is almost never compact, so to have a mapping object you need to allow some non-compact spaces.

Here's a proof that Stone spaces aren't cartesian closed.  By Stone duality, if they were, then Boolean algebras would be cocartesian coclosed.  In particular, coproducts (aka tensor products) of Boolean algebras would distribute over arbitrary products.  This is false: if $B$ is an infinite Boolean algebra and $(A_i)$ is an infinite family of nontrivial Boolean algebras, the canonical map $B\otimes \prod A_i\to \prod B\otimes A_i$ is not surjective.  (You can prove this, for instance, by noting that any element of $B\otimes \prod A_i$ comes from $B_0\otimes \prod A_i$ for some finite subalgebra $B_0\subset B$.)

Comment: Eric, thanks! Does this mean that Stone spaces are not monoidal closed as well? Or is it perhaps possible to define some other tensor product on them that makes them closed as a monoidal category?

Comment: I don't know of any closed monoidal structure on them.

Comment: Are Stone spaces weakly cartesian closed (that is, no uniqueness condition in the universal property of exponentials)?

Comment: @ssp8: No.  For instance, suppose you had a weak exponential object $2^X$ with evaluation map $ev:2^X\times X\to 2$, which is the characteristic function of a clopen subset of $2^X\times X$.  In particular, then, it is a finite Boolean combination of products of clopen subsets of $2^X$ and $X$.  So, it has only finitely many different intersections with sets of the form $\{a\}\times X$ (when you identify them with $X$).  This means that $ev$ induces only finitely many different maps $X\to 2$ via maps $1\to 2^X$.

Comment: Since $ev$ is supposed to be weakly universal, this means there can be only finitely many different maps $X\to 2$.  That is, a weak exponential object $2^X$ can only exist if $X$ is finite.